# Does slapping parts of your body increase blood flow and help with physical activity?

Tags: physiology, physical-fitness

I have believed for quite some time that slapping limbs is "good for blood circulation", without ever looking more into it. After getting curious about it, I found a lot of claims that it's good for many things, from emotional well-being to face skin tone, but no good evidence for it.

The closest I've found to a good source is [this rowing article](https://www.row2k.com/features/862/Slapping-Muscles-at-the-Line--Does-It-Help-/):

> A couple theories did emerge from those discussions, along the lines of the following:

> - believed to slow lactic acid build up (which does not seem to be based in science)
> - increases blood flow/keeps muscles loose (which does)
> - a habit that could be derived from the above

When looking on pubmed, I was unable to find anything related using "slap" and "tap" as keywords.

Does slapping parts of your body increase blood flow in a way that helps with physical activity?

Comment: Smack, strike, hit ...  Perhaps a consult with a thesaurus would help

Comment: Not good enough for an answer, but as per https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36752/is-there-a-purpose-for-this-slapping-at-the-top-of-reps, this is seen in various martial arts as a means to train to not be distracted by getting hit, and there's an unrelated practice in various calisthenics to set someone know they've done a good rep (I initially thought it had to do with blood flow).

Comment: I recall in a Found Footage Film Festival a "Caveman Workout" tape that advocated for beating your chest.